# Bing map URL not getting loaded in Firefox

Tags: firefox, bing-maps

I am using [Bing map URL](https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3&s=1&mkt=en-us&onScriptLoad=Loadmap) in my code. Map is getting loaded fine in IE, chrome and other browsers but Firefox.

I have modified https to http and removed query string 's=1' (SSL) from URL then it started working in Firefox (working fine in IE, chrome and others also). I would like to know what is causing problem with Firefox in this regard. How do i resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely in your code or in Firefox since the v6.3 control has been running fine in all other versions of Firefox for  years now and hasn't been updated in about 4 years. Note that v6.3 is nearing end of life and shouldn't be used in new apps. It was replaced by v7 about 4 years ago. V7 is much faster, has more features and is much more widely used. The documentation for v6.3 isn't even online anymore.